# libcurl и дополнительно подключаемые .lib/.dll - файлы

Tags: c++, c, curl

Вот скажите, а это нормально, когда все делаешь по инструкции:

-Собираешь библиотеку, в данном случае libcurl.

-Подключаешь статический .lib к проекту.

-Ставишь советующие #define CURL_STATICLIB

Компилируешь, и получаешь все равно ошибку "неразрешенного внешнего символа" и чтобы понять нужно или гуглить или смотреть в чем ошибки и в итоге оказывается, что не хватает подключенных Windows библиотек:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Normaliz.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Wldap32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Crypt32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")
```

И у меня собственно вопрос: почему их нужно подключать отдельно, почему они внутри libcurl`а сами не подключаются ? Ну или хотя бы в инструкции указывали бы.

Разве это правильно так делать?

Comment: К статическим библиотекам ничего не линкуется. Что-то линкуется только к бинарям (exe, dll).

Comment: @user7860670, ну внутри в коде же можно прописать типа условно: если static, если win32, то #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib") ?

Comment: Даже если не принимать во внимание отсутствие повсеместной поддержки `#pragma comment`, это все равно бы не работало. Например когда заголовочный файл с `#pragma comment` включается в единицу трансляции, которая собирается в еще одну статическую библиотеку.

Comment: а как ваши прагмы будут себя в gcc вести вы не думали?

Comment: @Sergey Tatarincev, да действительно не подумал. Но тогда бы хотя бы, где нибудь указали бы эту информацию :)

Comment: На будущее: `vcpkg install curl`