# libcurl - сборка c zlib

Tags: c++, c, curl

Позвольте еще один вопрос по подключению libcurl для Windows.

У самого решить проблему не получается ни как :(

Пытаюсь собрать libcurl с zlib статически debug по windows: для этого:

-скачал libcurl с офф. сайта

-скачал последнюю версию zlib с офф. сайта - zlib-1.2.11.

-собрал zlib статически под x32, debug в результате чего создались два файла - zlibstaticd.lib и zlibd.lib

-Далее следуя инструкции libcurl из папки project:

--создал папку  ---> куда скопировал хедеры zlib: zlib.h и zconf.h. и либы zlib: zlibstaticd.lib и zlibd.lib

--Так, как во время сборки - будет искаться по какому то косячному принципу файл - zlib_a.lib, хотя при сборке zlib такого файла вообще не создается, то я переименовал zlibstaticd.lib в zlib_a.lib. (и пробовал вариант с переименованием zlibd.lib в zlib_a.lib)

--Далее открыл native tools command promt vs 2019 (x86) и ввел следующую команду:

> nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static vc=16 debug=yes WITH_ZLIB=static
> ZLIB_PATH=C:\Users\Optimus1\source\repos\VS2019\LibCurl\Original_download\deps\lib\

Все собралось без ошибок, в итоге создался файл: libcurl_a_debug.lib

Приинклудил его к проекту, пытаюсь скомпилировать хотя бы пустой проект, но вылезают ошибки:

```
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _zlibVersion в функции _inflate_stream.

Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _inflate в функции _inflate_stream.

Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _inflateEnd в функции _exit_zlib

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _inflateInit_ в функции _inflate_stream. 

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _inflateInit2_ в функции _inflate_stream.
```

Почему эти ошибки в итоге появляются и с чем они связаны - понять к сожалению не получается.

Comment: zlib надо линковать к своему проекту

Comment: @user7860670, дополнительно к проделанным действиям ?

Comment: Вчера же уже писал по этому поводу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1353569/libcurl-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-lib-dll-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b#comment2400712_1353569

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо! Заработало. А подскажите, а что, тогда делает команда WITH_ZLIB=static ?

Comment: Без понятия, что делает эта команда.

Comment: @user7860670, однако, если собирать Libcurl без этой команды, то простое включение zlib.lib в проект - не работает.

Comment: @user7860670, а зачем тогда Nmake вообще ищет zlib_a.lib при сборке ?

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, откуда у вас взялся nmake, если вчера вы добавляли файлы в проект. WITH_ZLIB=static возможно как-то влияет на заголовочные файлы zlib, чтобы там не было dllimport например

Comment: @user7860670, вчера я пытался добавить файлы в проект, но у меня так этот проект и не скомпилировался из за ошибок. Поэтому я сделал "стандартным" способом через командную строку VS2019.